# C# Post , Webrequest Loop Not Working , loop for i = 2 then no result

Tags: c#, stream, http-post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

How can the following code be modified to loop , i tried the code without loop and it's working and i added the loop after 2 iteration i get no result and no error
i tried many solution from google but no progress , maybe because i am beginner

```
            Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
        session_Data[2] = unixTimestamp.ToString();

        try
        {
            string url = "";
            HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            IWebProxy proxy = request1.Proxy;
            if (proxy != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Proxy: {0}", proxy.GetProxy(request1.RequestUri));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Proxy is null; no proxy will be used");
            }

            WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
            Uri newUri = new Uri("http://" + ip + ":" + port);
            // Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
            myProxy.Address = newUri;
            // Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
            // Proxy property of request object.
            myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
            request1.Proxy = myProxy;

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "{\"device\"}";
            byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(postData);


            WebRequest request = request1;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());

            JObject session = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sr.Close();
            stream.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Error = ex.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, can you show the loop as well?

Comment: in another class , i receive ( ip , port, user , pass )

Answer (score 0):

Implement this inside a method and use async that you are able to wait for each reponse execution. Supply callback that will process completion of every request and you can use it in a loop :

```
 public async Task Process(Action ProcessFinished)
 {
    Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    session_Data[2] = unixTimestamp.ToString();

    try
    {
        string url = "";
        HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        IWebProxy proxy = request1.Proxy;
        if (proxy != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proxy: {0}", proxy.GetProxy(request1.RequestUri));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Proxy is null; no proxy will be used");
        }

        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
        Uri newUri = new Uri("http://" + ip + ":" + port);
        // Associate the newUri object to 'myProxy' object so that new myProxy settings can be set.
        myProxy.Address = newUri;
        // Create a NetworkCredential object and associate it with the 
        // Proxy property of request object.
        myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        request1.Proxy = myProxy;

        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string postData = "{\"device\"}";
        byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(postData);


        WebRequest request = request1;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);

        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());

        JObject session = JObject.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
        sr.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.Error = ex.Message;
    }
}

public static void ProcessFinished()
{
   //Do some work after each request
}

for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   await Process(ProcessFinished);
}
```